# Energy savings prediction model using stochastic processes and Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: time-series, model, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, fourier-transform

I want to build a model that quantifies the energy savings from a building retrofit project. For example a company is using a heating oil radiator system, that is meant to be replaced by a gas radiator system. I plan to model different factors that underly uncertainty, like oil price, gas price, energy use depending on temperature and maintenance costs etc. Subsequently applying MC to get the distribution of energy savings.

The two commodities oil and gas will be modelled by the Three Factor Model of Cortazar and Schwartz (2003). Prediciton itself will be conducted via R.

Energy use will be modelled by temperature as the only explanatory variable, as suggested in Dhar et al. (1999). Its based on Fourier Series Model.

A good and realistic assumption will be made of the maintenance costs/hours.

The next step would the predicition of all four variables with time horizon T and hence, four distribution function can be derived. This will be followed by a Monte Carlo Simulation to determine the distribution of energy savings.

1. Generally: Is it feasible the way I plan to do it? Might any problem occur when performaing these steps in R?
2. Does someone know R packages that suit this purpose?
3. Any other variables that might be implemented in this model?
4. Or are there any suggestions how to model commodities and/or weather?

Im just a bit overwhelmed right now, regarding the feasibility of the model, even though I have done a lot of research so far...

Some help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I have been researching and developing causal time series forecasting models incorporating monte carlo forecast simulation methods to enable effective decision making under uncertainty even taking into account the possibility of future anomalies. While financial planning may appear to be far afield from your stated problem I believe there is a strong similarity requiring good statistical forecasting and monte carlo. The following paper http://gfoa.org/sites/default/files/FinancialPlanningInUncertainTimesAgenda.pdf used free tools available from http://probabilitymanagement.org/ via http://prob

Answer (score -1):

While model building is very important .... creating probability distributions via simulation can be equally important. These distributions are not assumed to be normal as the empirical distribution of the model errors may not be precisely normal or anything in particular.

To further elaborate on my comment [image] which I believe provides a partial answer to your question "Does someone know R packages that suit this purpose?" I have attached a pix which suggests a generality of approach. The forecasting component ( much more general than your suggestions) is available in R to provide the XML files i.e. the simulated family of forecasts for each input series needed for the probability management app.